Troubles with pointers to char array in C
I have written the following code in C:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_NAMES 5
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20
char* names[MAX_NAMES];
void addNames();
int main(){
    addNames();
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_NAMES; i++){
        // printing "name" from array
        printf("Name from array #%d: %s\n", i+1, names[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
void addNames(){
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_NAMES; i++){
        printf("Give me the name #%d: ", i+1);
        fgets(name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH, stdin);
        name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';
        // adding "name" to array "names"
        names[i]=name;
        // printing "name" from array
        printf("Name given: %s\n", names[i]);
    }
}

It declares a global variable names of type pointer to char array (char*). In addNames() everything works fine. I can store the input of the user in variable name of type char[MAX_NAME_LENGTH], then save it to the array names and print the names.
But once I left addNames() module and return to main(), if I try to print the names from the array, it will come with extrange strings:

I think this occurs because the pointers saved in the array names are being "destroyed" when returning to main() from addNames() since those pointers were created there.
Sorry for any typo or redundance, I'm not a native speaker xD. Hope you can help understand what's happening, and how could I fix this, or what approach would work better. Thx

Your hunch is correct. The local name variable only exists while addNames() is actively running. You can obtain a pointer to name, but the memory where it was stored is reclaimed once it returns, so now the pointers to it are meaningless.

Even if it were valid, the pointers all point to the same buffer which gets overwritten by each entry. Suggest names[i] = strdup(name);

@500-InternalServerError thanks, I'm glad I kinda figured it out xD.

@WeatherVane strdup(name) made it. Thank you so much :D

You are dealing with a few interesting issues.
Array size ≠ Number of elements in use
The first is that your array has a declared size, and you are requiring the user to give you exactly that many names. I recommend you also track the number of names actually used and give the user the opportunity to supply fewer.
char* names[MAX_NAMES] = {NULL};
int num_names = 0;

The way to do this can be as simple as recognizing when the user just presses Enter without entering a name. Your instruction can be as simple as:
Enter a maximum of 20 names. Press Enter twice to finish:

strdup()
Now, to add a name to your list, simply:
    // add a dynamically-allocated copy of name to the end of our list of names
    names[num_names++] = strdup(name);

If you use strdup(), you must also free() the used names:
int main(void){
    // get the names
    addNames();

    // print the names
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<num_names; i++){
        printf("Name from array #%d: %s\n", i+1, names[i]);
    }

    // free the names
    for(int i=0; i<num_names; i++){
        free(names[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

strcpy()
Instead of an array of pointers, you could have an array of strings.
char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
int num_names = 0;

Now you can use strcpy() to make a copy of the string obtained from the user.
    // copy the name to the end of our list of names
    strcpy(names[num_names++], name);

And with this you no longer need to free() anything.
fgets() & newline
You should check the results of your input operations to verify they worked.
    if (!fgets(name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH, stdin)) crash_and_burn();
    char * nl = strpbrk(name, "\n\r");
    if (!nl) crash_and_burn();
    *nl = '\0';

If attempt to read from file fails, then the program should fail.
Likewise, if the user supplied a line that is too long, the program should fail.
The reason is simple: if the user does not supply correct input, make the program fail. Require the user to supply correct input!
Globals
People will give you grief about globals. They aren’t as evil as everyone likes to repeat, but the phrase “Globals are Evil” is a way of saying that you should consider their impact.
For a homework solution, no big deal. For lots of programs, no big deal.
It is when things start to get complex that globals start making life more difficult than it need be.
Consequently, for the future, you should begin considering ways to do this without using global variables. For example, you could rewrite your function signature to:
int add_names(char* names[]);

or:
int add_names(char names[][MAX_NAME_LENGTH]);

Then in main() you can get the names as:
int main(void){
    char* names[MAX_NAMES] = {NULL};
    int num_names = 0;

    num_names = add_names(names);

}

Variations abound, but the gist is that you have moved the names (and name count) data from a global object to one that can be localized.

Wow, what a complete answer. Knowing different approaches is awesome. My hate to C strings is slowly decreasing xD. Thank you for the knowledge
